SSIS: Trying to Utilize an "Execute Process Task" to Run a Python Program that will Output Multiple Variables I can Use as Inputs in Future Tasks
I'm trying to do a very simple thing in SSIS.  Execute a Python Script that will output multiple user variables I can then pass as inputs for future SSIS tasks.
I can setup the "Execute Process Task" and run the python program.  But I don't know how to exit individual output variables into my SSIS package.
For instance, I have the simple program ("rumble.py"):
if __name__ == "__main__":

    user_ssis_variable1 = "Let's"
    user_ssis_variable2 = "get"
    user_ssis_variable3 = "ready"
    user_ssis_variable4 = "to rumble!"
    
        print("Test Complete!")
        print("|" + user_ssis_variable1 + "|" + user_ssis_variable2 + "|" + user_ssis_variable3 + "|" + user_ssis_variable4 + "|")

In SSIS, I did find a workaround that instead of individual variables being populated, I can instead pass a single output string with all the information I need to a defined user variable as follows:

Here, the "Executable" is the path to my python.exe app.  The "Arguments" is the path to my python file "rumble.py" (located in "E:\...\rumble.py").  And the "StandardOutputVariable" is a newly defined string variable called "Python_Output".
With this setup, when I run the "Execute Process Task", I do see the user defined variable "Python_Output" populate as a single string containing all printed text from the executed python program "rumble.py": "Test Complete!\r\n|Let's|get|ready|to rumble!|\r\n"

Hence, a workaround solution is to use this single output variable and parse the string utilizing the pre-embedded "|".  The first split[0] would contain the "Test Complete!" text.  The following splits would contain the variables.  That is, split[1] returns user_ssis_variable1, split[2] user_ssis_variable2, split[3] user_ssis_variable3, and split[4] user_ssis_variable4.  The last split[5] would be just a paragraph marker and can be ignored.
In the aforementioned workaround solution, I could use various substring arguments to parse, index, and locate all the information I need and be done with it.  But what I want to know from the community is the following:
Is there a cleaner, more structured way to pass these outputs to individual user defined variables inside SSIS?
That way, instead of returning a long text string that I need extra code to parse whenever I call them later, I could return each output in its own defined variable so it can be utilized cleanly through the program.  Such that I have 4 distinct variables instead of one:

"User::user_ssis_variable1"
"User::user_ssis_variable2"
"User::user_ssis_variable3"
"User::user_ssis_variable4".

If the workaround solution I shared is the best, please indicate that.  Otherwise, I would like to know the more efficient, proper solution.  The one utilized most by seasoned SSIS developers.
Thank you!!

It may be easier to write a C# script task to parse out the strings (C# does better/easier parsing than the expressions).  You could have a simple C# script task you pass the string to and have it parse out and return the 4 variables.  Or you could do it with SQL code as well in a SQL task, but may be more difficult in SQL.

Thank you, Brad.  I could indeed add an "Execute SQL Task" which would parse the output into the 4 separate variables.  For learning I would be curious how you would write C## code to do this.  I'm not as versed on C## and would love to see the solution for this.

You would need to use a C# script task.  Pass in the variable with the string, then in C# there are a few ways to do it, split string function into an array, then loop through and set your 4 variables.  Then return them on output.  One thing I do though for writing C# script tasks in SSIS is to write it in a console app first (new app in VS) to make it a LOT easier to test/play with and get working, then transfer code to SSIS (will need some tweaks to get it into the SSIS) but a good way to practice and debug C# script task because debugging those in SSIS are very hard.
